# Seasonal Website, split between Winter / Summer, best approach?

Tags: wordpress, seo, redirect

I am building a site for a client who runs a chalet. The website has content split into two sections, summer and winter.

The user can navigate between the two sites, and upon arriving at the homepage of the site for the first time they will be directed to the homepage of either the winter, or summer site, depending on the date.

What are the SEO implications of this, and suggested best practise.

Am I best to use a 301 redirect for the homepage, which then directs to the relevant summer / winter homepage. Or am I best to build a splash page (urgh!) with a selection between the two sites.

(The content for the most part is distinct between the two sections.)

Comment: Not really an answer, but what about something along these lines (http://visithumbervalley.com/) with a simple selection; it's saved in a cookie (or was it just a session variable?) for the next time they visit and defaults to either season by the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *not* use a 301 redirect on this as it will hurt you with SEO.

Furthermore, I would not chose the site depending on the current date as the current date might have nothing to do with the season people are looking for (consider that they might want to book for the future).

I would make an initial page that directs to both and has some general information that's applicable to both.

Comment: What type of redirect do you think would better suited if I did go down that route?

Comment: I would not use a redirect at all because what the search engines look for is stability over time. There is a pretty good webmaster guide for Google, you might want to have a look at it.

Comment: I think I just have a strong dislike of splash pages! Thanks for checking out my stuff!

Comment: I understand, but in this case you might be thwarting what the user wants to do if they happen to go to the site in the wrong season. That could be really annoying. And you could do it in a way that the initial page provides some value.